# ipython notebook hang when open a large notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am using the LATEST (2.2.0) ipython notebook, when I create a notebook with a loop to write many lines (about 20000 lines), then it run forever I guess since I always see the running icon at the top right. Even if I restart the computer and reopen the notebook again, it will into a running mode automatically, then I almost unable to do anything in this page. I have to copy the code and new another page to fix it.

How can I fix such hang issue during open a too large notebook? I have tried the kernel "interrupt" and "restart" menu and it seems no any effect at all.

Comment: The same issue happen to me also! maybe you need to ensure the output data not too bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPython notebook is not intended to do such tasks with too much calculation or too many output data because actually such things is for standalone program rather than a notebook.

To fix such issues, you need to create a standalone application (script) to do it from console, then paste the meaningful result into IPython notebook.